# admin-ajax returning 0 - not submitting form data to db

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to send form data to a table called `attendants`. I have the form, the AJAX and query created, but when trying to test (when submitting the form), I see a `POST http://localhost/rsvp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)` error on console.

Unsure what's causing this as when I run a `console.log(ajaxurl);` the URL it returns is `http://localhost/rsvp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` which is correct.

Unsure what's happening here?

EDIT: I've recently discovered that `http://localhost/rsvp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` returns `0`.

**form.php** (**Folder Path**: rsvp > template-parts > parts > form.php) :

```html
<div class="form sectionPadding" id="rsvp-form">
  <form id="rsvpForm" method="post">
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/snippets/form-step-1'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/snippets/form-step-2'); ?>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
</script>
```

**form.js** (`form.js` compiles into `theme.min.js`. The path to `theme.min.js` is rsvp > assets > build > js > theme.min.js) :

```js
jQuery('#rsvpForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  jQuery.ajax({
    action: 'send_to_db',
    dataType: "text",
    type: "post",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    url: ajaxurl,

    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("Error");
    }
  });


});
```

**functions.php**

```html
add_action("wp_ajax_send_to_db", "send_to_db");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_send_to_db", "send_to_db");

function send_to_db(){
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  global $wpdb;

  $first_name = $_POST['fname'];

  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "attendants";
  $row_result = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table_name (first_name) VALUES ('$first_name')" );

  if ($row_result == 1){
   echo "submitted";
  } else{
   echo "error";
  }

  die();
 }
}
```

To summarize, my folder structure is:

```
rsvp
   assets
      build
         js
            theme.min.js
   template-parts
      parts
         form
            form.php
            form.js
functions.php
```

Comment: HTTP 400 error is not like 404 (file not found) - it's a *bad request* error - `the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).`

Comment: @JaromandaX - Right, I initially read it was to do with missing hooks in other questions. But my hooks are aslo present in `functions.php` so unsure what is causing this

Comment: how is the path `rsvp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` related to anything in `fuctions.php`? I don't see it

Comment: @JaromandaX - Not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: the url is `http://localhost/rsvp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` ... does this file exist?

Comment: @JaromandaX - Yes, it exists, I haven't changed anything in the `wp-admin` folder

Comment: oh, right ... you mentioned something about functions.php, thought that was somehow relevant

Comment: @JaromandaX `functions.php` is just where I'm running the query to send data to the database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EDIT: I've recently discovered that
>   `http://localhost/rsvp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` returns 0.

That's indeed the expected return value when the request (URL) doesn't contain the AJAX [action](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/#action) name. Additionally, the HTTP response status would also be a `400 Bad Request` which basically means "missing action name" or "there's *no callback registered* for that action".

#### And in your case, it seems that your AJAX script is not sending the AJAX action.

Because in your `form.js` script, the `action` parameter should be in the `data` — and as far as I know, `jQuery.ajax()` doesn't have a `action` property:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  action: 'send_to_db', // this should be in 'data'
  ...
  data: $('form').serialize(),
  ...
});
```

So you can do `data: $('form').serialize() + '&action=send_to_db'` like so:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  ...
  data: $('form').serialize() + '&action=send_to_db',
  ...
});
```

That way, WordPress would recognize the AJAX action (via `$_REQUEST['action']`) and then run the proper AJAX [handler / PHP callback](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/enqueuing/#ajax-action), which is `send_to_db()` in your case.

And you can confirm if your AJAX callback is registered properly by visiting `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=send_to_db` — are you still seeing a `0`?

### Update

1. If the HTTP response status is no longer `400` (where it should now be `200`), then it means your AJAX request is sending an action (`send_to_db` in your case) and that there's a PHP callback registered for that AJAX action (`wp_ajax_send_to_db` / `wp_ajax_nopriv_send_to_db`).

   But because your callback is only doing something when the POST variable `submit` is set, then if your AJAX request data doesn't include that, the response would still be a `0`.

   If you want to avoid that, then you can do something like so:

   ```php
   function send_to_db() {
       if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
           // ... your code here.
           //die();
       } else {
           echo 'Invalid request!';
       }

       wp_die(); // It's recommended to always call this to end an AJAX request,
                 // but die() is OK, too.
   }
   ```

   And with that, when you *manually go to* `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=send_to_db` (i.e. without sending any POST data), you'd see `Invalid request!` on the page. `window.fetch( '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=send_to_db' )` would even receive that same response.

   So now that the error `400` is gone, you just need to make sure your AJAX request is sending the proper data and that your PHP callback is working (or doing what it needs to do). And on Chrome, you can easily inspect the request and response data, headers, etc. by opening the developer tools and go to the [Network → XHR tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#analyze) and simply click on the relevant request.
2. Your SQL query is highly *insecure* and I strongly suggest you to use [`wpdb::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to prepare the query for safe execution:

   ```php
   //$row_result = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table_name (first_name) VALUES ('$first_name')" );
   $query = $wpdb->prepare(
       "INSERT INTO $table_name (first_name) VALUES (%s)",
       sanitize_text_field( $first_name )
   );
   $row_result = $wpdb->query( $query );
   ```

   Alternatively, for inserting a *single database row/entry*, you can just use [`wpdb::insert()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/):

   ```php
   $row_result = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
       'first_name' => sanitize_text_field( $first_name ),
   ) );
   ```

And I have actually tested your original PHP callback, and it worked, so long as the request data are good. :)

Comment: Hi Sally, thanks for your answer. I've added `data: $('form').serialize() + '&action=send_to_db'` to `form.js` and completed the form to test. Good news, I don't see a `(Bad Request)` error on console any more. However, the `console.log(data);` I have as the `success` function, it logs `0` and nothing is being inserted into my database. I can also confirm that going to `http://localhost/rsvp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=send_to_db` still returns a `0`

Comment: I hope the "Update" part helps?

Comment: Thanks a ton Sally, not only for showing me the correct path, but also explaining things to me. I can confirm that I've got it working now :) Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad I could help and thank you for the bounty :) But would you mind to mark the answer as correct? It's just nice to see that green icon/indicator on questions with an accepted solution, you know.. ;)