# WP_Query Ajax pagination get 0 as result instead of load more posts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a custom loop with wp_query, this is a table showing the orders placed by a user. Everything works fine, content displayed, pagination and data are ok.

To test I am showing 4 results per page, what I am trying to do is dynamically load other results with ajax pagination. I want that when I click on page 2 another 4 posts are loaded instead of loading another page.

Now the ajax call seems to work, when I click on page 2 it loads correctly but as a result I get 0 instead of loading other posts. Why is this happening ?

**Template.php**

```
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/main.js?<?php $FourDigitRandomNumber = mt_rand(00000,99999); echo $FourDigitRandomNumber; ?>" defer=""></script>

<h3>Custom Endpoint</h3>
<div id="content">
<?php
global $wp_query;

$paged = max( 1, (int) filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'pagina' ) );
$order_statuses = array('wc-completed');

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'shop_order',
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_status'    => $order_statuses,
    'customer_id'     => get_current_user_id(),
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$post_count = $loop->found_posts;

// The Wordpress post loop
if( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    
    // The order ID
    $order_id = $loop->post->ID;
   
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
    $order = wc_get_order($loop->post->ID);
    $items = $order->get_items();

    $orders_id = $order->get_id();
    $status =  wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );
    $date_created = $order->get_date_created()->date('d/m/Y');
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method_title();
    $order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();

      foreach ( $items as $item ) {
       $product_name = $item->get_name();
       $view_order = $order->get_view_order_url();

       // Get product image - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/
       $product = $item->get_product();
         if( $product instanceof WC_Product ){
          $order_img = $product->get_image();
         }

       //Get product download button 
       $downloads = $order->get_downloadable_items();
         if(is_array($downloads)) {
             foreach($downloads as $product){
              $download_button = '<a href="'. $product['download_url'] .'" target="_blank">Download</a>';
             } 
         } 

         echo '
                <table class="table_orders">
                <tr class="table_row_items">
                    <td class="product_number">
                     <span class="mobile title">Ordine</span>
                     <span>#'. esc_attr($orders_id) .'</span>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_name">
                     <span class="mobile title">Prodotto</span>
                     <a href="'. wp_kses_post($view_order) .'">'. wp_kses_post($product_name) .'</a>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_data">
                     <span class="mobile title">Data</span>
                     <span>'. wp_kses_post($date_created) .'</span>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_price">
                     <span class="mobile title">Prezzo</span>
                     <span>'. wp_kses_post($order_total) .'</span>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_status">
                     <span class="mobile title">Stato</span>
                     <span class="label ' . $order->get_status() . '">'. wp_kses_post($status) .'</span>
                    </td>
 
                    <td class="product_action">
                     <span class="mobile title">File</span>
                     <a target=”_blank” href="'. esc_url($view_order) .'">Visualizza<i class="fa-duotone fa-eye"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>    
                </table> 
             ';
      }
    }
}
  
  // Pagination
   if ( $post_count > 4 ) {
      ?><div id="pagination" class="container-pagination"><?php 
       $args = array(
      'base'          => esc_url( 'https://motustrength.it/account/custom/' ) . '%_%',
      'format'        => '?pagina=%#%',
      'total'         => $loop->max_num_pages,
      'current'       => $paged,
      'show_all'      => false,
      'end_size'      => 3,
      'mid_size'      => 3,
      'prev_next'     => true,
       'prev_text' => __('<i class="fa-regular fa-angle-left"></i><span>Indietro</span>'), 
      'next_text' => __('<span>Avanti</span><i class="fa-regular fa-angle-right"></i>'),
      'type'          => 'plain',
      'add_args'      => false,
      'add_fragment'  => ''
      ); 
      echo paginate_links($args); 
   }
   

else {
   ?><div class="no-downloads-msg">Nessun download disponibile, non hai ancora acquistato alcun prodotto.</div><?php
   } 
 ?></div><?php
```

**File Js**

```
(function( $ ) {
    
    $.fn.wpPagination = function( options ) {
        options = $.extend({
            links: "a",
            action: "pagination",
            ajaxURL: "https://" + location.host + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            next: ".next"
        }, options);
        
        function WPPagination( element ) {
            this.$el = $( element );
            this.init();
        }
        
        WPPagination.prototype = {
            init: function() {
                this.createLoader();
                this.createEnd();
                this.handleNext();
                this.handleLinks();
            },
            createLoader: function() {
                var self = this;
                $('#pagination').prepend( "<span id='pagination-loader'>Loading...</span>" );
                $('#pagination-loader').hide();
            },
            createEnd: function() {
                var self = this;
                $('#pagination').prepend( "<span id='pagination-end'>End</span>" );
                $('#pagination-end').hide();
            },
            handleNext: function() {
                var self = this;
                var $next = $( options.next, self.$el );
            },
            handleLinks: function() {
                var self = this,
                $links = $( options.links, self.$el ),
                $pagination = $( "#pagination" );
                $loader = $( "#pagination-loader" );
                $end = $( "#pagination-end" );
                
                $links.click(function( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $('#pagination .next').fadeOut();
                    $loader.fadeIn();

                    var $a = $( this ),
                    url = $a.attr("href"),
                    page = url.match( /\d+/ ),
                    pageNumber = page[0],
                    data = {
                        action: options.action,
                        page: pageNumber,
                        shop_order: $('#pagination-post-type').text()
                    };
                    
                    $.get( options.ajaxURL, data, function( html ) {
                        $pagination.before( "<div id='page-" + pageNumber + "'></div>" );
                        $pagination.before( html );
                        $a.attr("href", url.replace('/' + pageNumber + '/', '/' + ( parseInt(pageNumber) + 1 ) + '/'));
                        
                        if ( !html ) {
                            $('#pagination .next').remove();
                            $loader.fadeOut();
                            $end.fadeIn();
                        } else {
                            $loader.fadeOut();
                            $('#pagination .next').fadeIn();
                            //smoothScroll($('#page-' + pageNumber), 85);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        };
        
        return this.each(function() {
            var element = this;
            var pagination = new WPPagination( element );
        });
    };
    
    $(function() {
        if( $( "#pagination" ).length ) {
            $( "#pagination" ).wpPagination();
        }
    });
    
})( jQuery );
```

**Functions.php**

```
// ajax pag
function get_posts_for_pagination() {
    $html = '';
    $paged = ( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $post_type = $_GET['shop_order'];

    if ( empty($post_type) ) {
         return '';
    }

    if( filter_var( intval( $paged ), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) ) {

        $paged = max( 1, (int) filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'pagina' ) );
        $order_statuses = array('wc-completed');
        
        $args = array(
             'post_type'      => 'shop_order',
             'paged'          => $paged,
             'posts_per_page' => 4,
             'post_status'    => $order_statuses,
             'customer_id'     => get_current_user_id(),
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        $post_count = $loop->found_posts;
        
        // The Wordpress post loop
        if( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
             $loop->the_post();
            
             // The order ID
             $order_id = $loop->post->ID;
            
             // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
             $order = wc_get_order($loop->post->ID);
             $items = $order->get_items();
        
             $orders_id = $order->get_id();
             $status =  wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );
             $date_created = $order->get_date_created()->date('d/m/Y');
             $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method_title();
             $order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
        
                foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                 $product_name = $item->get_name();
                 $view_order = $order->get_view_order_url();
        
                 // Get product image - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/
                 $product = $item->get_product();
                    if( $product instanceof WC_Product ){
                     $order_img = $product->get_image();
                    }
        
                 //Get product download button 
                 $downloads = $order->get_downloadable_items();
                    if(is_array($downloads)) {
                         foreach($downloads as $product){
                          $download_button = '<a href="'. $product['download_url'] .'" target="_blank">Download</a>';
                         } 
                    } 
        
                    echo '
                        <table class="table_orders">
                        <tr class="table_row_items">
                                <td class="product_number">
                                    <span class="mobile title">Ordine</span>
                                    <span>#'. esc_attr($orders_id) .'</span>
                                  </td>
             
                                  <td class="product_name">
                                    <span class="mobile title">Prodotto</span>
                                    <a href="'. wp_kses_post($view_order) .'">'. wp_kses_post($product_name) .'</a>
                                  </td>
             
                                  <td class="product_data">
                                    <span class="mobile title">Data</span>
                                    <span>'. wp_kses_post($date_created) .'</span>
                                  </td>
             
                                  <td class="product_price">
                                    <span class="mobile title">Prezzo</span>
                                    <span>'. wp_kses_post($order_total) .'</span>
                                  </td>
             
                                  <td class="product_status">
                                    <span class="mobile title">Stato</span>
                                    <span class="label ' . $order->get_status() . '">'. wp_kses_post($status) .'</span>
                                  </td>
         
                                  <td class="product_action">
                                    <span class="mobile title">File</span>
                                    <a target=”_blank” href="'. esc_url($view_order) .'">Visualizza<i class="fa-duotone fa-eye"></i></a>
                                  </td>
                        </tr>    
                        </table> 
                        
                    ';
                }
            } wp_reset_query();
       }
    } 
    
    echo $html;
    exit();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_pagination', 'get_posts_for_pagination' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pagination', 'get_posts_for_pagination' );
```

Comment: You're getting a 0 because you're not calling the right 'action' when you actually make your ajax call.  This gist you found is a lot of extra crap that you don't need.  Make sure your actual ajax call's action is `pagination` it makes no sense to me why you would dump it into an object then call it on the same function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [admin-ajax returning 0 - not submitting form data to db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944666/admin-ajax-returning-0-not-submitting-form-data-to-db)

Comment: @HowardE Thank you for your suggestion. I guess there are a lot of things I don't need, I got the code from github to have a reference. I then had in mind to gradually adapt it to my needs. I am new to all of this and am trying to learn.

Anyway, I followed the post you suggested and added  `data:"action = pagination",` in fn.WpPagination, now I don't get the 0 anymore but it doesn't load any posts and status code is 200.

I'm not sure I get it right, I would be very grateful if you could write an example answer to refer to.

Comment: There must be literally thousands of references on using WP Ajax. I've seen your recent posts, and am familiar with your efforts to customize the My Account pages. You need to understand what the jQuery ajax request is actually doing, which is simply firing a php function based on user actions on the front end.  Here is a simple loadmore posts using Ajax - https://gist.github.com/DuckDivers/e62dbd991c7a50368d9fc1015be7d492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have found a solution even if it was not what I was trying to do, maybe I was wrong from the beginning. The idea was to go to page 2 without reloading the page. With the code below, instead of going to page 2, other elements are simply added to the already existing elements.

Also, if I wanted to add the same ajax function to another template I would have to add more code to the functions.php. I think it is a very dirty and not very functional practice.

Anyway I leave the "correct" code for the workaround.

**Template.php**

```
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/custom.js?<?php $FourDigitRandomNumber = mt_rand(00000,99999); echo $FourDigitRandomNumber; ?>" defer=""></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/custom.css?<?php $FourDigitRandomNumber = mt_rand(00000,99999); echo $FourDigitRandomNumber; ?>" />

<h3>Custom Endpoint</h3>

<?php
global $wp_query;

//Variable For Args Query
$paged = max( 1, (int) filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'pagina' ) );
$order_statuses = array('wc-completed');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_status'    => $order_statuses,
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
// Loop Content
if( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();

  //Here content
  // The order ID
  $order_id = $loop->post->ID;
   
  // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
  $order = wc_get_order($loop->post->ID);
  $items = $order->get_items();

  $orders_id = $order->get_id();
  $status =  wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );
  $date_created = $order->get_date_created()->date('d/m/Y');
  $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method_title();
  $order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();

  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item->get_name();
    $view_order = $order->get_view_order_url();

    // Get product image - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/
    $product = $item->get_product();
      if( $product instanceof WC_Product ){
       $order_img = $product->get_image();
      }

    //Get product download button 
    $downloads = $order->get_downloadable_items();
      if(is_array($downloads)) {
          foreach($downloads as $product){
           $download_button = '<a href="'. $product['download_url'] .'" target="_blank">Download</a>';
          } 
      } 

      echo '
      <table class="table_orders">
      <tr class="table_row_items">
      <td class="product_number">
           <span class="mobile title">Ordine</span>
           <span>#'. esc_attr($orders_id) .'</span>
          </td>

          <td class="product_name">
           <span class="mobile title">Prodotto</span>
           <a href="'. wp_kses_post($view_order) .'">'. wp_kses_post($product_name) .'</a>
          </td>

          <td class="product_data">
           <span class="mobile title">Data</span>
           <span>'. wp_kses_post($date_created) .'</span>
          </td>

          <td class="product_price">
           <span class="mobile title">Prezzo</span>
           <span>'. wp_kses_post($order_total) .'</span>
          </td>

          <td class="product_status">
           <span class="mobile title">Stato</span>
           <span class="label ' . $order->get_status() . '">'. wp_kses_post($status) .'</span>
          </td>

          <td class="product_action">
           <span class="mobile title">File</span>
           <a target=”_blank” href="'. esc_url($view_order) .'">Visualizza<i class="fa-duotone fa-eye"></i></a>
          </td>
      </tr>    
      </table> 
 ';
  } 
}
    
    // Pagination
      ?><div id="pagination" class="container-pagination"><?php 
        $args = array(
      'base'          => esc_url( 'https://motustrength.it/account/custom/' ) . '%_%',
      'format'        => '?pagina=%#%',
      'total'         => $loop->max_num_pages,
      'current'       => $paged,
      'show_all'      => false,
      'end_size'      => 3,
      'mid_size'      => 3,
      'prev_next'     => true,
        'prev_text' => __('<i class="fa-regular fa-angle-left"></i><span>Indietro</span>'), 
      'next_text' => __('<span>Avanti</span><i class="fa-regular fa-angle-right"></i>'),
      'type'          => 'plain',
      'add_args'      => false,
      'add_fragment'  => ''
      ); 
      echo paginate_links($args); 
    
}  

else {
   ?><div class="no-downloads-msg">Nessun download disponibile, non hai ancora acquistato alcun prodotto.</div><?php
   } 
 ?></div><?php
```

**File.js**

```
(function( $ ) {
    
    $.fn.wpPagination = function( options ) {
        options = $.extend({
            links: "a",
            action: "pagination",
            ajaxURL: "https://" + location.host + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            next: ".next",
            previous: ".previous",
            disablePreviousNext: false
        }, options);
        
        function WPPagination( element ) {
            this.$el = $( element );
            this.init();
        }
        
        WPPagination.prototype = {
            init: function() {
                this.createLoader();
                this.handlePreviousNextLinks();
                this.handleLinks();
            },
            createLoader: function() {
                var self = this;
                self.$el.before( "<div id='pagination-loader'></div>" );
            },
            handlePreviousNextLinks: function() {
                var self = this;
                var $previous = $( options.previous, self.$el );
                var $next = $( options.next, self.$el );
                
                if( options.disablePreviousNext ) {
                    $previous.remove();
                    $next.remove();
                } else {
                    $previous.addClass( "clicked" );
                    $next.addClass( "clicked" );
                }
            },
            handleLinks: function() {
                var self = this,
                    $links = $( options.links, self.$el ),
                    $loader = $( "#pagination-loader" );
                    
                    $links.click(function( e ) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var $a = $( this ),
                            url = $a.attr( "href" ),
                            page = url.match( /\d+/ ), // Get the page number
                            pageNumber = page[0],
                            data = {
                                action: options.action, // Pass the AJAX action name along with the page number
                                page: pageNumber
                            };
                            
                          if( !$a.hasClass( "clicked" ) ) { // We don't want duplicated posts
                            
                            $loader.show(); // Show the loader
                            
                            $.get( options.ajaxURL, data, function( html ) {
                                $loader.hide(); // Hide the loader
                                $loader.before( html ); // Insert posts
                                $a.addClass( "clicked" ); // Flag the current link as clicked
                            });
                            
                           }
                    });
            }
        };
        
        return this.each(function() {
            var element = this;
            var pagination = new WPPagination( element );
        });
    };
    
})( jQuery );

(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
        if( $( "#pagination" ).length ) {
            $( "#pagination" ).wpPagination();
        }
    });
    
})( jQuery );
```

**functions.php**

```
// Ajax Pagination
function my_get_posts_for_pagination() {
    $paged = $_GET['page']; // Page number
    $html = '';
    $pag = 0;

    if( filter_var( intval( $paged ), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) ) {
        
        $order_statuses = array('wc-completed');
        $pag = $paged;
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'shop_order',
            'paged'          => $pag, // Uses the page number passed via AJAX
            'posts_per_page' => 4, // Change this as you wish
         'post_status'    => $order_statuses,
            'customer_id'    => get_current_user_id(),
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        
        // The Wordpress post loop
        if( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
             $loop->the_post();
                // Build the HTML string with your post's contents
            // The order ID
            $order_id = $loop->post->ID;
   
            // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
            $order = wc_get_order($loop->post->ID);
            $items = $order->get_items();

            $orders_id = $order->get_id();
            $status =  wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );
            $date_created = $order->get_date_created()->date('d/m/Y');
            $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method_title();
            $order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();

            foreach ( $items as $item ) {
               $product_name = $item->get_name();
               $view_order = $order->get_view_order_url();

               // Get product image - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/
               $product = $item->get_product();
               if( $product instanceof WC_Product ){
                  $order_img = $product->get_image();
               }

               //Get product download button 
               $downloads = $order->get_downloadable_items();
               if(is_array($downloads)) {
                  foreach($downloads as $product){
                     $download_button = '<a href="'. $product['download_url'] .'" target="_blank">Download</a>';
                  } 
               }
               
                    //What you want to show
               echo '
                  <table class="table_orders">
                  <tr class="table_row_items">
                     <td class="product_number">
                      <span class="mobile title">Ordine</span>
                      <span>#'. esc_attr($orders_id) .'</span>
                     </td>

                     <td class="product_name">
                      <span class="mobile title">Prodotto</span>
                      <a href="'. wp_kses_post($view_order) .'">'. wp_kses_post($product_name) .'</a>
                     </td>

                     <td class="product_data">
                      <span class="mobile title">Data</span>
                      <span>'. wp_kses_post($date_created) .'</span>
                     </td>

                     <td class="product_price">
                      <span class="mobile title">Prezzo</span>
                      <span>'. wp_kses_post($order_total) .'</span>
                     </td>

                     <td class="product_status">
                      <span class="mobile title">Stato</span>
                      <span class="label ' . $order->get_status() . '">'. wp_kses_post($status) .'</span>
                     </td>

                     <td class="product_action">
                      <span class="mobile title">File</span>
                      <a target=”_blank” href="'. esc_url($view_order) .'">Visualizza<i class="fa-duotone fa-eye"></i></a>
                     </td>
                  </tr>    
                  </table> 
               ';
               }
               wp_reset_query();
           }
       }
    }   
    echo $html;
    exit();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_pagination', 'my_get_posts_for_pagination' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pagination', 'my_get_posts_for_pagination' );
```