# Wordpress ajax returns 0 only

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using datatables in which I've implemented a `<select>` tag, I am trying to create a dependent dropdown but the problem is ajax returns only 0,

Also when I `alert(data)` in success function, the alert comes up with `[object Object]` reponse, not sure what's going wrong.

For testing purpose I've putted the `echo "<option value='test'>Test</option>";`

```js
$('#data-modification-table tbody').on('change', 'td select', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      action: "send_dropdown_account_data",
      account_id: $tr.find('.user_account_name').val(),
      project_id: $tr.find('.user_project_name').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function(req, status, err) {
      console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
    }
  });
});
```

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_dropdown_account_dat', 'update_modification_dropdown_options');
add_action('wp_ajax_send_dropdown_account_dat', 'update_modification_dropdown_options');    

function update_modification_dropdown_options()
{
  echo "<option value='test'>Test</option>";
  $output = ob_get_clean();
  wp_send_json_success($output);
  wp_die();
}
```

Inside inspect's network option I can see this response for admin-ajax.php:  `{"success":true,"data":"0"}`

In console there is no error or message.

Comment: there are many questions. what `ajaxurl` points to? plugins? custom endpoint? also, what do `send_dropdown_account_data` meant? it looks like your javascript is ok, given **"in console there is no error or message"** and it returns 0 data.

Comment: Thanks for response, as I've already mentioned in the question ajaxurl menas `http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` Moving to another question, send_dropdown_account_data means the name of action and sending an ID (account_id) along with it, you can see all these things in code itself.

Comment: Would probably be great, if the name of the action you send with your AJAX request, and that of those you registered, would actually match. `action: "send_dropdown_account_data"` in your JS, but in your add_action calls you used `wp_ajax_nopriv_send_dropdown_account_dat `/`wp_ajax_send_dropdown_account_dat`, both missing the `a` at the end ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [admin-ajax returning 0 - not submitting form data to db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944666/admin-ajax-returning-0-not-submitting-form-data-to-db)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echoing the output you should just return an array of data instead directly to the `wp_send_json_success` method.

E.g.

```
$data = [
    'input' => '<option value="test">Test</option>',
];

wp_send_json_success($data);
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/

The response will be returned in that AJAX call as JSON.

`alert(data.input)`

Comment: @p-dawson thanks for the solution, I got the alert reponse `undefined`

Comment: better to use wp_send_json(), since you have control over the status code - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/ What is the logic always to send success response, if your code fails?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing action name in `add_action();`

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_dropdown_account_data', 'update_modification_dropdown_options');
add_action('wp_ajax_send_dropdown_account_data', 'update_modification_dropdown_options');
```

Try this one in ajax function.