# WordPress Admin Ajax 400 error, returning 0

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation, admin-ajax

I've created an AJAX request to send data to my plugin which will then submit a job application. When submitting the form the page that it is returning is blank other than a 0 and the console is showing a 400 error for admin-ajax.php.

**This code has now been updated from Plamen's suggestions, I realise the $data variable now may not be doing anything**

The action of my form is below:

```
<form method="POST" id="job-application-form" action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>" class="flex lg:flex-row flex-col flex-wrap">
```

This is the code on my form page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#job-application-form').on('submit', function(e) {
            var form = $(this);
            var data = form.serialize();
            
            $.post(form.attr('action'), data, function(response) {
                console.log(form.attr('action'));
                alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
            });
            
            e.preventDefault();

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the code on my plugin function:

```
<?php

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_submit_post', 'submit_post' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_post', 'submit_post' );

    function submit_post() { 

        $actual_link = parse_url('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        $parts = explode('/', $actual_link['path']);
        $job_id = $parts[count($parts)-1];

        $curl = curl_init();

        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
        // $info = $_GET['info'];

        $data = array(
            'firstName' => $firstName,
            'lastName'  => $lastName,
            'email'     => $email,
            'phone'     => $phone,
            'address'   => $postcode,
        );
        $payload = json_encode($data);

        var_dump($job_id);
        var_dump($payload);

        $token_url = "/home/.token";
        $file = fopen($token_url, "r") or die("Unable to open job ads file!");
        $access_token_new = fread($file,filesize($token_url));

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => The API URL . $job_id .'/applications',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token_new,
                'Content-Type: application/json',
            ),
        ));

        fclose($file);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        var_dump($response);

        wp_die();
    }

?>
```

From what I've gathered my ajax request cannot find my plugin function but I'm not sure if I've messed up the naming or what's going on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [admin-ajax returning 0 - not submitting form data to db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944666/admin-ajax-returning-0-not-submitting-form-data-to-db) your action 'submit_post' isn't defined.

Comment: I'm sending the data to an API so needs to go through an Curl POST request, but this is interesting thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the payload of the HTTP POST request in a compatible format.

The simplest would be to change your code to the following:

Add a hidden field named "action" with as follows:

```html
<form method="POST" id="job-application-form" action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>" class="flex lg:flex-row flex-col flex-wrap">
  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit_post">
</form>
```

Then change your JavaScript implementation like this, no need to get the Ajax URL with PHP, you have it in the `<form>` action attribute:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#job-application-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    var data = form.serialize();
      
    $.post(form.attr('action'), data, function(response) {
       console.log(form.attr('action'));
       alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
    
    e.preventDefault();

    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Plamen, thanks for this but it's still giving me the same error message, I can see the payload is fine and it was being encoded in my php function but still getting the same 400 error

Comment: Can you update your question with details how is your PHP end-point function being resisted, in what file, and what hook.

Comment: I've now updated the question with my full plugin function

Comment: But how is this PHP code being included in your WordPress setup?

Comment: My understanding was that the action in the form should trigger the hook in the plugin to run the function, guessing this is incorrect?

Comment: You need to add the `add_action( 'wp_ajax_submit_post', 'submit_post' );` and `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_post', 'submit_post' );` code to either your plugin init or theme `functions.php` script.

Comment: Ok we seem to be getting somewhere, I've tested it in both my plugin main file and my functions file and both are giving me a 500 error now, any ideas?

Comment: I've commented out the $_POST variables and the $data array and passed the data variable directly to the $payload variable minus the json_encode as it is already serialised. I can see in the payload it is being delivered but im getting a 500 error saying there has been a critical error

Comment: It seems that the 500 error may be coming from the CURL request... so I guess this would be a new question.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking, my guess would be that the data variable isn't being passed across correctly or the job ID in the CURL URL isn't being picked up

Comment: Ok this has worked for passing the data to my PHP function as I've commented out the whole PHP CURL request and var_dump'd a success message to show the function is now working on submit. I can see the data is in the payload so just need to get my CURL request working correctly now